# File is corrupted when uploaded in sFTP Server

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib

When I uploaded a file it will convert to .zip in laravel storage (not corrupted, can still export) but when I uploaded it in our server using **sFTP** and when I extract the .zip file in the server, It became a corrupted .zip file.

```
            $sftp = new SFTP($this->api_host);
            if(!$sftp->login($this->ftp_user, $this->ftp_password)) {
                return false;
            }
```

file path to be uploaded

```
            $file = base_path().$this->destinationPathZipped;
```

creating folder in server

```
            $sftp->mkdir($tempFolder);
```

change permission of the temp folder

```
            $sftp->chmod(0777, $tempFolder, true);
```

change directory to folder

```
            $sftp->chdir($sftp->pwd().'/'.$tempFolder.'/');
```

upload file using sftp
$filename = name of zip file (ex: ZCW123.zip)

```
            $s = $sftp->put($filename, $file.$filename);
```

The code above is how I upload my file using sftp in our server.
I am using phpseclib/sftp, the version of my laravel is 5.1

the `echo $sftp->getSFTPLog()` after `$sftp->put()` is here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORGmF.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're creating a file who's contents are basically the file name itself.

Try this:

```
$s = $sftp->put($filename, $file.$filename, SFTP::SOURCE_LOCAL_FILE);
```

Comment: The question is duplicate. Do not answer it. Vote it to be closed as duplicate.